# Problema de cotejamiento en MySQL

Tags: mysql

Tengo una **base de datos** en MySQL con respectivos datos repartidos en tablas. La base de datos ya está creada y tengo un problema de que **no lee bien los carácteres** como:

1. tildes
2. acentos
3. ñ

**¿Qué ocurre?**

He probado a realizar las siguientes sentencias pero no se soluciona:
He probado las siguientes sentencias sin suerte:

```
ALTER DATABASE dbname CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
ALTER TABLE tbl_name CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
```

**Anotaciones**

La base de datos está definida de la siguiente manera:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ejemplo de visualización:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Al parecer estas guardando los textos como [cadenas con entidades `HTML`](https://dev.w3.org/html5/html-author/charref)

Comment: @Marcos ¿Cómo se puede traducir al lenguaje castellano: con acentos, tildes, ñ, etc? ¿Algún cotejamiento correcto? ¿Se puede?

Comment: Esto no parece ser un problema de traduccion de lenguaje, si no de como fueron guardados los datos

Comment: @gbianchi ¿Entonces se puede resolver?

Comment: Podrias hacer un proceso que los transforme?

Comment: ¿No existe la posibilidad de que cambiando el cotejamiento o creando una nueva base de datos con el .sql que tengo de caracteres con entidades HTMl los transforme automáticamente a lenguaje castellano?

Comment: @omaza1990, ¿por que quieres "ver" los textos con [signos diacríticos](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signo_diacr%C3%ADtico)? ¿en que proceso u operación, este formato te afecta? PD: hasta donde se, para corregir los textos vas a tener que hacer un `script`.

Comment: Me afecta porque al leer los datos en la página web salen con los textos: cadenas con entidades y no se leen correctamente. Es decir, se lee: Renovaci&oacute;n en lugar de Renovación. Ese es el problema.

Comment: @omaza1990, Me parece entonces que se podría pensar que el problema esta en como "imprimes" los textos en la página web. ¿Podrías actualizar tu pregunta y agregar el código que tienes para imprimir los textos?

Comment: @Marcos Si pongo todo el HTML la gente no entendería la pregunta... ¿Abrimos chat?

Comment: @omaza1990, pasa que como te comento gbianchi, no es un problema de cotejamiento, sino de como fueron guardados los datos. Desde mi punto de vista tienes 2 opciones, o corriges los textos guardados mediante un script o corriges como muestras los datos en la página web. En otras palabras, tu pregunta como esta actualmente no tiene solución.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/73454/discussion-between-omaza1990-and-marcos).

Answer (score 0):

Si quieres que te tome el campo tal cuál viene puedes tratar tu columna como si fuera del tipo ***binary*** o ***blob***.

Algo así como:

```
select [nombre_campo] **like binary** from [nombre_table]
```

Comment: Quiero que esos caracteres especiales se transformen en caracteres del idioma castellano. Es decir, que en lugar de que me muestre "&eacute;" me muestre "é".